# Issue in Spark kafka integration through python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was facing this issue while integrating spark Kafka through python. I have changed all the spark libraries but still face the same issue.

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "D:/Work/kafka_wordcount.py", line 18, in 
>           kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
>         File "D:\softwares\ApacheSpark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py",
>   line 70, in createStream
>         File "D:\softwares\ApacheSpark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**
>         File "D:\softwares\ApacheSpark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.createStream.
>       : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>               at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>               at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>               at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.K`enter code here`afkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:81)
>               at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:151)
>               at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:555)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 26 more

Please suggest any solution. This is the source code:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic],{"bootstrap.servers": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
                  .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am using python for integrating spark-kafka, with the following details:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.0 kafkacount.py localhost:9092 test_spark

spark version is 1.6.1.
python 2.6
kafka-client 0.10
```

I have already changed spark library and kafka library but did not get the output.

Comment: Do you have any source code you can show us? What is you're program trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am building a simple word count program through kafka spark python

Comment: Please, update with the versions of scala, kafka jar you are using and how do you run the job, e.g. `spark-submit.... ` (Also take a look at [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py#L26) )

Comment: I have taken code from that link which you have shared .
Thanks but still I am facing the issue

Comment: Any suggestio on it